# Inserting a control before another control

Tags: asp.net

How do I dynamically insert a control before another control in asp.net. Lets say control1 is some control on the web page and I want to dynamically create and insert a table just before control1.

e.g.

```
table1 = new Table();
table1.ID = "Table1";
```

but what comes next? To add a control as a child I would do: `control1.Controls.Add(table1);` but how on earth do I insert table1 as the previous sibling of control1 ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want the new control (`controlB`) to be immediately before `controlA`, you can determine the index of `controlA` in the `Page.Controls` collection, and insert `controlB` at that location. I believe this will bump `controlA` forward by one index, making them immediate siblings as desired.

```
if(Page.Controls.IndexOf(controlA) >= 0)
    Page.Controls.AddAt(Page.Controls.IndexOf(controlA), controlB);
```

**Edit:**

One further note - the above assumes control A and B are on the root page level. You could also use the `Parent` property to ensure the sibling insertion works no matter where `controlA` sits in the page hierarchy:

```
Control parent = controlA.Parent;

if(parent != null && parent.Controls.IndexOf(controlA) >= 0)
{
    parent.Controls.AddAt(parent.Controls.IndexOf(controlA), controlB);
}
```

I'd actually prefer this method as it is more flexible and does not rely on the `Page`.

Comment: In which event would you call this? Because I always get The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.

Comment: I was just looking at AddAt for the first time and things are a bit haywire. I was pretty sure it had something to do with the master page but I'm not sure. Can you explain what you mean by `the root page level`? Having some trouble knowing what to look up.

Comment: Just checked the parent and I think it is the master page messing with things. The parent of the control I'm dealing with is `ContentPlaceHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `control1.Controls.AddAt(0, table1)`?  Kind of odd they didn't call the method Insert like most other collection types.

Comment: Would not control1.Controls be the child controls of control1?

I need to insert just prior to control1, on the same level.

Comment: Whoops!  Sorry, I misunderstood.  Looks like you have found a solution though.