# Insert a control before another control inside a ItemDataBound event

Tags: asp.net

I tried to [Solution suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281541/inserting-a-control-before-another-control), but it didn't work in my case. using `Page.Controls.IndexOf()` for any of the elements on my page, when called in the `ItemDataBound` event method, returns -1.

I need to insert a linebreak based on certain conditions for stuff generated by my Data repeater. Here is the method:

```
private String lastCharacter = "";
public void users_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HyperLink link = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("micrositeLink");

    Tuple<String, String> user = (Tuple<String, String>)e.Item.DataItem;
    link.NavigateUrl = "/" + user.Item1;
    link.Text = user.Item2;

    // makes a break in the data when going from one bunch of data to another.
    if (user.Item1.Length >= 2)
    {
        if (lastCharacter == "")
            lastCharacter = user.Item1[1].ToString().ToLower();
        else if (lastCharacter != user.Item1[1].ToString().ToLower())
        {
            HtmlGenericControl lineBreak = new HtmlGenericControl("br");
            if (Page.Controls.IndexOf(link) >= 0)
                Page.Controls.AddAt(Page.Controls.IndexOf(link), lineBreak);

            lastCharacter = user.Item1[1].ToString().ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

The bound data is a list of users in my system with names beginning with a particular letter. My goal is to further sub-divide this data with a line break between groups of data that have the same second letter. For instance:

```
AaPerson    Aarad    AaStuff
Aathing

AbItem    AbStuff

Acan    Achandle
```

To me, inserting a line break before the elements where the second letter changes is the obvious solution, but other suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: Why are you casting `e.Item.DataItem` to type `Tuple`?

Comment: This is the underlying dataItem: `List<Tuple<String, String>> users = getUsers(Request.QueryString["letter"]); micrositeList.DataSource = users; micrositeList.DataBind();` The reason I am using a Tuple rather than something typed is that Typed things make problems with the `HttpRuntime.Cache`.

Comment: Have you considered using `DataBinder.Eval` in the `ItemDataBound` event instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `e.Item.Controls.IndexOf` instead:

```
if (e.Item.Controls.IndexOf(link) >= 0) 
    e.Item.Controls.AddAt(e.Item.Controls.IndexOf(link), lineBreak);
```